# Firebase Cloud Messaging function sendToDevice not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using the following code to send a notification from one device to another using FCM. Everything works fine until before `return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...)`. The 'Token ID: ' log displays token ID of the receiver, but when I set the variable token_id to the sendToDevice function, the notification is not called, therefore the notification is not sent.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
 const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

 console.log('We have a notification to send to ', user_id);

 if(!event.data.val()){

  return console.log('Notification has been deleted from the database: ', notification_id);

 }

 const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
 return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

  const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

  console.log('You have a new notification from ', from_user_id);

  const user_query = admin.database().ref(`/usuarios/${from_user_id}/nome`).once('value');
  return user_query.then(userResult => {

   const user_name = userResult.val();

   const device_token = admin.database().ref(`/usuarios/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
   return device_token.then(result => {
       
    const token_id = result.val();

    console.log('Token ID: ', token_id);

    const payload = {
     notification: {
      title: "New Request",
      body: `${user_name} has sent you a request.`,
      icon: "default",
     },
     data: {
      p_tab: "2"
     }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{

     console.log('Notification sent to ', user_id);

    });

   });

  });

 });

});
```

**EDIT** Code I use to save Firebase Instance ID to the current user's database.

```js
String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

usersRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("device_token").setValue(deviceToken);
```

Comment: has the log `You have a new notification from ` printed? You can see the log from console.firebase.google.com in `function section`

Comment: Yes. All the logs but the "Notification has been sent to...".

Comment: Two debugging options: (1) add code to check the result of `sendToDevice()` [using this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L67-L73) (2) copy the token output in your log and paste it into the Firebase console page for sending notifications to confirm your device receives and handles the notification.

Comment: @BobSnyder, the log output I received by implementing what you've suggested was `Error: Invalid registration token provided. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM`. Weird. Very weird. I edited my post adding the code I use to register the Firebase Instance ID to the current user's database everytime it signs in to my app. Is there something wrong there?

Comment: I don't see any errors with your token handling. The `token_id` logged by your cloud function should be 152 characters.

Comment: The following is the current token ID returned by Firebase Instance and it's the same `token_id` returned as log output, and it has 152 characters: `f3HtVeLr1ZU:APA91bEncoHleZFvJEUlJsdmoTp3u0Aog4l3kBpLcq1Z3QeNQjo5dp3N3TNSdzhVoRdlc8aC_5wOzNk3tU99T6EZ_xksjOpOlUSyAMM5SGlJIQnIuzaIIAQfr9xO6yrxg29ZAzq7lfv8`. I'm using Facebook auth method to sign in to the app features, but I don't think it's a problem, is it? Should I be saving current user's Facebook access token as the current user's `device_token` value?

Comment: That looks like a valid token.  No, the auth tokens are not used for device messaging.

Comment: I managed to make it work! Thanks, @BobSnyder!

Comment: @WilerJr Are you receiving notifications now ? How did you achieve this ,i am not receiving any notifications but functions are running successfully .

Comment: Hi, @AdarshGumashta. It's been almost a year, but here I am again! Have you managed to make it work? If not, I think I can help you.

Comment: @WilerJr Ya i got it worked :) , anyways thnx for help :)

Comment: Glad to know! :)