# Firebase function messaging errors on send with invalid-recipient

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the Firebase console error:

```
Error: Unknown error code: messaging/invalid-recipient.
    at new HttpsError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:97:19)
    at createCloudMessage (/workspace/src/create-notifications.js:20:11)
    at /workspace/src/create-notifications.js:36:5
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I save the token in my client app to firestore:

```
const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
await firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).update({fcmToken: fcmToken});
```

And send message in my firebase function:

```
const createCloudMessage = async (message, type, to_user_id) => {
  try {
    // get users fcmToken
    const user = await db.collection('users').doc(`${to_user_id}`).get();
    if (user.exists) {
      const {fcmToken} = user.data();
      if (fcmToken) {
        // send FCM
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: 'Notification',
            body: message,
          },
        };
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload);
      }
    }
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      error.code || 'unknown',
      error.message,
    );
  }
};

exports.onCreateNotifications = functions.firestore
  .document('notifications/{docId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const id = context.params.docId;
    const data = snap.data();
    const {message, type, to_user_id} = data;
    // create reward notification
    createCloudMessage(message, type, to_user_id);
  });
```

Note: Similar to [Firebase Cloud Messaging function sendToDevice not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423966/firebase-cloud-messaging-function-sendtodevice-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

After rebuilding my app via XCode logging out the user and logging back in and running this again - the code worked. So please note the above is a correct working way to handle sending FCM to individual users device.